# How to change mapStateToProps from javascript to typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following `mapStateToProps` that works fine in *javascript*:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({application}) => {
  const applicationComposite = application;

  return {applicationComposite};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(App);
```

I am trying to migrate to *TypeScript*, so I changed the method to type the parameter to `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (application: object) => {
  const applicationComposite = application.applicationComposite;

  return {applicationComposite};
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Property 'applicationComposite' does not exist on type 'object'.  TS2339

    20 | 
    21 | const mapStateToProps = (application: object) => {
  > 22 |   const applicationComposite = application.applicationComposite;
       |                                            ^
    23 | 
    24 |   return {applicationComposite};
    25 | }
```

How can I handle this issue in *TypeScript* if every `mapStateToProps` has a different object as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```ts
interface IAppProps {
  applicationComposite: any;
}

interface IReduxStore { // Should be defined in redux store. Just for example.
  application: any;
}

class App extends React.Component<IAppProps> {
  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ application }: IReduxStore): IAppProps => {
  const applicationComposite = application;

  return { applicationComposite };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(App);
```

Comment: I made the change you propose, and it worked, but I just got stuck in another *TypeScript* error: `Property 'currentApplicationComponent' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Omit<ClassAttributes<App> & ApplicationStateInterface, "applicationComposite">'.  TS2741

    12 |   <React.StrictMode>
    13 |     <Provider store={store}>
  > 14 |       <App />
       |        ^
    15 |     </Provider>
    16 |   </React.StrictMode>,
    17 |   document.getElementById('root')`

Comment: Try to remove `{}` from export: `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);`

Answer (score 0):

I found here that I have to use another Redux util to make the props resulting from the connect a type, and then declare the component to receive the props of such type:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect, ConnectedProps} from 'react-redux';
import logo from './assets/logo.png';
// import { Counter } from './features/counter/Counter';
import './App.css';

import {IApplicationState} from './features/application/reducers';

const mapStateToProps = (application: IApplicationState) => {
  const applicationComposite = application.applicationComposite || {};

  return {applicationComposite};
}
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

interface Props extends PropsFromRedux {};

class App extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <span>
            <span>Attractora </span>
            {this.props.applicationComposite && <span>{this.props.applicationComposite.content}</span>}
          </span>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```